# How to launch the QMainWindow with a fading animation?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I tried launching my window this way:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    setWindowOpacity(0);

    QGraphicsOpacityEffect* eff = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(this);

    QPropertyAnimation* ani = new QPropertyAnimation(eff, "windowOpacity");
    ani->setDuration(3000);
    ani->setStartValue(0);
    ani->setEndValue(1);
    ani->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::OutBack);
    ani->start(QPropertyAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
}
```

---

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

But the window never became visible, I would like to it be initialized with a fade in effect.

What's the proper way to achieve it?

Comment: `QGraphicsOpacityEffect` has no property named [`windowOpacity`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsopacityeffect.html#properties).  Did you mean `opacity` instead?

Comment: @G.M. I tested with `opacity` continues the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues I see. First, as originally written, your main function is going to exit immediately after opening the window. Add `return a.exec();` at the end of main.

Next, you are animating `QGraphicsOpacityEffect`. As written, your example code has no connection between `QGraphicsOpacityEffect` and the window. Your animation is animating the property on the effect class, but that doesn't propagate back to the widget. There is no need to use `QGraphicsOpacityEffect`. Instead, just animate the widget directly:

```
    ui.setupUi(this);

    setWindowOpacity(0);

    // Notice that the first argument passed in is 'this' - the widget.
    // the widget is what you want to animate.
    QPropertyAnimation* ani = new QPropertyAnimation(this, "windowOpacity");
    ani->setDuration(3000);
    ani->setStartValue(0);
    ani->setEndValue(1);
    ani->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::OutBack);
    ani->start(QPropertyAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
```

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, I have fixed it. The window still doesn't perform the animation nor became visible.

Comment: You want to modify the property of the widget, so I would think you would want QPropertyAnimation(this, "windowOpacity"). As written, there is no connection between the animation and the window.

Comment: Does the animation work at your side?

Comment: I have very similar code to you that works. However, as stated in my last comment, my `QPropertyAnimation` is animating the windowOpacity property of the widget directly. I am not using `QGraphicsOpacityEffect`.

Comment: Dean, could you provide an example? i don't understand what property i should be using.

Comment: I have added more information to my answer that should clarify things a bit.

Comment: When I use the animation the window is not shown in the center of my screen, do I need to recalculate the XY position where it will be shown?