# Start-of-Program signal Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am currently calling an animation function when I press a push button with `on_pushButton_3_clicked()`. However, I want it to execute right away when the program starts. Is there a way to do this with the same inbuilt function that reads the name of components in the .ui file?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
void myClass::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    // Animation Function Code
}
```

Comment: You might want to look at [this (probably) related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74621772/how-to-launch-the-qmainwindow-with-a-fading-animation).

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to solve this is to trigger a timer:

```
#include <QTimer>

...
int main()
{
    ...

    QTimer::singleShot(100, [=](){ emit myClassObj.on_pushButton_3_clicked(); });
    ...
    app.exec();
}
```